# Fourier transform of $x\left ( t \right )= t\cdot e^{-t^{2}}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Knowing that the Fourier transform of the function $y\left ( t \right )= e^{-t^{2}}$ is equal to $\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac{\omega ^{2}}{4}}$
 I then proceeded using the the derivative rule
$$\mathcal {F}\left [ te^{-t^{2}} \right ]=-i\sqrt{\pi} \frac{\omega }{2}e^{-\frac{\omega ^{2}}{4}}$$ However my answer is not listed as a possible solution. I tried tackling this problem by using definition, but there appeared some nasty integrals.

Comment: Your approach is correct, maybe you just made some computation mistake.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  What were the listed answers?

Comment: Make sure you are using a different definition of fourier transform. Does it have a similar form?

Comment: I will type them out later. The do look similar, indeed, differing only by a factor a factor of $\sqrt2$